# How to Hide the Android Manifest Permissions

Tags: android, android-manifest

is there any way for hide the `android manifest` ***Permissions*** for some reasons and user couldnt see during installing the app?

Comment: I hope this is not possible.

Comment: it means, the developer cannot hide the permissions? or obfuscate the Manifest? or this is outside of client and related to the Rom and firmware?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taken from the support page from [Google Play](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/6014972?hl=en):

> Google Play shows you which permission groups an app will be able to
>   access. This information can help you decide whether you want to
>   install the app.

The whole sole purpose of those permissions is for people to see what your app can access and decide whether they want to share (all) that information with you.

Answer (score 1):

In Android L and lower, this is impossible. If you do not ask for a permission, you will get a crash when you try to access the thing that needs permission. Thus, you cannot hide permissions from users.

In Android M, the whole permission idea is changed: instead of asking for lots of permission at the install, the app is installed without permissions, and when you need a specific permission, for example for camera, the user will have the option of accepting or declining the permission. Thus, the user will have a clearer view of what a permission is asked for.

Comment: i know about the Android M.so, we cannot hide the permissions in Android M?

Comment: You cannot hide permission in any version of Android, whether all of them are asked at install (Android L and lower), or each permission is asked when needed (Android M).